# Is it possible to refer to alias before it is assigned?

Tags: syntax, alias

Does the query shown below work? (Sorry for this type of question, but I am a novice and it is not possible for me to run it right now).

```
SELECT
   table.id 
   SUM(10/ta.value) AS amount 
JOIN tableA ta 
         ON ta.key = t.key
```

What I am curious about if it is possible to refer to a alias "before" (i.e higher up) it has been assigned.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it will not work. You are missing a comma after your first column, and a FROM clause. You can use table aliases (as you have here with ta) in the manner you have. However, in SQL Server you can't refer to a column alias in certain areas (GROUP BY, etc). You should tag your version of SQL Server.

Comment: What DBMS is this about?

Comment: There is a logical sequece in which the clauses are processed. Later clauses can reference earlier clauses. For an example see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement

Answer (score 4):

FROM is - logically - evaluated before SELECT, so despite the textual order of your query, ta is known to SUM.

There are however a number of things in your query that won't work:

1. You need a FROM clause
2. A JOIN is performed between 2 tables

You can probably rewrite your query to:

```
SELECT table.id 
     , SUM(10/ta.value) AS amount 
FROM tableA ta
WHERE ...
```

but perhaps this is what you meant?

```
SELECT t.id 
     , SUM(10/ta.value) AS amount 
FROM ... as t
JOIN tableA ta 
     ON ta.key = t.key
WHERE ta.key = t.key
GROUP BY t.id
```

Note that you need a GROUP BY for the latter query

The link provided by [Jim Horn](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/147837/jim-horn) below is a good start towards a better understanding, so I'll just add a few lines on a methodology for constructing a query.

Step one, figure out what relations that are involved and how the relate. Example:

```
FROM customers as c
JOIN orders as o 
    ON c.custno = o.custno
```

SQL is closed under operations like JOIN, UNION and so forth, meaning that the result is a new relation. It is normally not given a name, but in this case, we can think of it as customer_orders

Step two, what customer_orders are we interested in?

```
FROM customers as c
JOIN orders as o 
    ON c.custno = o.custno
WHERE year(order_date) = 2019
```

What details of these customer_orders are we interested in? In this example, I'll assume that we want to know how many orders each customer have:

```
SELECT c.custno, count(o.orderno)
FROM customers as c
JOIN orders as o 
    ON c.custno = o.custno
WHERE year(order_date) = 2019
GROUP BY c.custno
```

It is not valid to refer to an aggregate function in the where clause, since the `where clause` is evaluated before the aggregation (count(...)), but there is a similar construction that can be used. Say that we want to know which customers that have more than 20 orders:

```
SELECT c.custno, count(o.orderno)
FROM customers as c
JOIN orders as o 
    ON c.custno = o.custno
WHERE year(order_date) = 2019
GROUP BY c.custno
HAVING count(o.orderno) > 20
```

This is the same as:

```
SELECT custno, cnt
FROM (
    SELECT c.custno, count(o.orderno) as num_orders
    FROM customers as c
    JOIN orders as o 
        ON c.custno = o.custno
    WHERE year(order_date) = 2019
    GROUP BY c.custno
) as customer_orders
WHERE num_orders > 20
```

Finally, you may want to retrieve the rows in a particular order.

```
SELECT c.custno, count(o.orderno)
FROM customers as c
JOIN orders as o 
    ON c.custno = o.custno
WHERE year(order_date) = 2019
GROUP BY c.custno
HAVING count(o.orderno) > 20
ORDER BY count(o.orderno) desc -- most orders first
```

Up until the last step the result is a relation, but the order by invalidates the fundamental property that a relation is unordered. It may seem like an irrelevant note, but it is much easier for the DBMS in question to optimize a query if it does not have to take the order of rows in consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Lennart's answer is correct.  To make things a little clearer for you I'll ask that you change your definition of 'before' from this..

```
SWEATY (SELECT)
FEET (FROM, with JOINs)
WILL (WHERE)
GIVE (GROUP BY)
HORRIBLE (HAVING)
ODORS (ORDER BY)  (Good luck getting that out of your head)
```

... to follow the Query Order of Execution ([link](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-an-sql-query)) which is how the query is processed, and is a different order then how it is typed.

Looking at the link, any alias defined in a section can be used by any section below it.

Comment: The link has generally correct info but misinforms in some minor details: the ON clause(s) are part of the FROM clause and there is no OUTER clause. LEFT/RIGHT/FULL OUTER JOIN are operators.